# Passing Data onChange from child to parent? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, communication

I need to passing data from child to parent but on change.

Child component code:

```
  <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*"
        (change)="handleInputChange($event)">
```

Parent component:

```
 <app-file-uploader></app-file-uploader>  //this is child component
```

I need pass ($event) to parent component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Angular's `Output()` directive. This is how it's done:

**First:** In your child component, add the following import statement:

```
import { Output } from '@angular/core';
```

**Second:** In the child component class: add the following property:

```
@Output() onChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Now in your `handleInputChange($event)`, you need to emit the onChange property:

```
handleInputChange($event){
    // ... all of your logic
    this.onChange.emit($event); // this will pass the $event object to the parent component.
}
```

**Finally:** In your parent component template, you can call your component like this:

```
<app-file-uploader (onChange)="callSomeFunction($event)"></app-file-uploader>
```

**Note:** replace `callSomeFunction` with whatever function you're calling.

Here's the [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#how-to-use-output) on how to use Output(). Hope this answer helps you!